# Use the default profile to install istio-1.5.0 on k8s-1.15, the istio-proxy meet the istio-token pemission denied problem

Tags: go, kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

The istio-1.5.0 install with default profile on k8s-1.15, the istiod does fail to startup. Because the access permission of istio-token is wrong, check the istiod, the permission of istio-token file is istio-proxy, but there is no read and write permission.

filemode:  -rw------ , can not be access by istio-proxy ，only for root user.

```golang
func (s *eterver) EnableCA() bool {
    if s.kubeClient == nil {
        // No k8s - no self-signed certs.
        // TODO: implement it using a local directory, for non-k8s env.
        log.Warn("kubeclient is nil; disable the CA functionality")
        return false
    }
    /*because istio-proxy has  no  privilige to access the file, that mad the istiod can't start up*/
    if _, err := ioutil.ReadFile(s.jwtPath); err != nil {
        // for debug we may want to override this by setting trustedIssuer explicitly.
        // If TOKEN_ISSUER is set, we ignore the lack of mounted JWT token, it means user is using
        // an external OIDC provider to validate the tokens, and istiod lack of a JWT doesn't indicate a problem.
        if features.JwtPolicy.Get() == jwt.JWTPolicyThirdPartyJWT && trustedIssuer.Get() == "" {
            log.Warnf("istiod running without access to K8S tokens (jwt path %v); disable the CA functionality", s.jwtPath)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Try to modify the permissions of the token file in the pilot code, and find that the file is readonly and cannot be modified, but readonly=false has been configured in the configuration file:

```yaml
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/istio
    name: istiod-ca-cert
  - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
    name: istio-token
    readOnly: false
  - mountPath: /var/run/ingress_gateway
    name: ingressgatewaysdsudspath
  - mountPath: /etc/istio/pod
    name: podinfo
  - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs
    name: ingressgateway-certs
    readOnly: false
  - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs
    name: ingressgateway-ca-certs
    readOnly: false
```

Other related configuration items are as follows:

```yaml
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - ALL
  runAsGroup: 1337
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1337
```

Can anyone give some advice or help?

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/35571

Comment: You are using very old (deprecated) version of Istio and Kubernetes. Did you try to test your problem with newest versions?